# Выбор системы храненея таблиц, целесообразность и суть использования индексов и внешних ключей MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. 
Недавно начал изучать MySQL. И тут же столкнулся с довольно не простыми на мой взгляд вопросами. Например, у меня стоит задание создать базу данных "универ".
Есть таблици:

- students (id, name, patronymic, surname, faculty, course, phone_number, m_id(mothers.id), f_id(fathers.id), gr_id(groups.id));
- groups (id, name);
- mothers (id, name, patronymic, surname, job, phone_number);
- fathers (id, name, patronymic, surname, job, phone_number);
- teachers (id, name, surname);
- disciplines (id, name);
- marks (id, st_id(students.id), d_id(disciplines.id), t_id(teachers.id), mark);

Во - первых, если, к примеру, о родителях студента есть информация о маме, а родители в разводе, тогда f_id будет NULL? Вообще если ставить значение поля m_id или f_id, каким их лучше ставить. ведь если INT NOT NULL, выходит при отсутствии информации об одном из родителей поле не может пустовать?

Какую систему хранения лучше выбирать для таблиц. Ведь, если я понял целесообразнее будет выбрать InnoDB, может она и уступит по скорости работы с SELECT, но я смогу использовать для таблиц ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE CASCADE? Тут возникает новый вопрос, а какая разница между CASCADE и RESTRICT (CASCADE обновляет значения в
дочерних таблицах при изменении или удалении записей в родительских таблицах, а RESTRICT - при изм. или удалении в род., ничего не меняет в дочерней, если значения род. уже используются в дочерней. Смысл использовать RESTRICT, когда CASCADE автоматически обновит или удалит записи в род. и дочерней таблицах)?

Не совсем понятно что такое индексы и нужны ли они мне в данной БД. Насколько я понял, индекси групируют записи по определенным значениям в разных кластерах диска и ускоряют поиск,но это ведь не внешние ключи? Правильно ли я понимаю, что внешние ключи связывают таблици, а индексы групируют записи в таблицах?????

Корректно ли с точки зрения специалистов в области администрирования БД, данная структура и ответьте пожалуйста, стоит ли применять индексы мне и вообще что следует сделать. Информацию читал с разных сайтов. 
Просьба не писать, что ТС дурак, голосовать против и говорить, что вопросы надо было разбить на отдельные. Я считаю, что все они связаны и разбивать их не имеет смысла. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У человека могут отсутствовать и один и оба родителя. Поэтому ссылка на родителей не может иметь флаг `NOT NULL`
2. InnoDB если нет других требований (например, может понадобиться MEMORY). Если Вы сомневаетесь какой движок использовать - используйте InnoDB
3. RESTRICT/CASCADE/SET NULL Рассмотрим Ваш пример с оценками. При удалении студента (выгнали) его оценки никого не интересуют, поэтому их можно удалять каскадно (CASCADE). Нельзя удалить предмет, если студент по нему имеет оценку (RESTRICT). При удалении учителя (уволился) мы можем сбросить на него ссылку при этом сама оценка останется (SET NULL)
4. Индексы. Представьте, что перед Вами два шкафа с книгами. В одном книги отсортированы по алфавиту (индексированы), а в другом стоят как попало. В каком шкафу Вы быстрее найдете книгу? При создании внешнего и первичного ключа индексы на эти поля создаются автоматически. Индекс создается на конкретное поле. И одно поле в таблице может быть проиндексировано, а второе нет. Соответственно будет разное выполнения запроса где в условии запроса или сортировке стоит одно поле и другое
5. По структуре таблиц у меня одно замечание: т.к. таблицы `mothers` и `fathers` ничем не отличаются, то их нужно слить в одну таблицу `parents`

Comment: интерисуют три вопроса: 1) объясните,если Вас не затруднит 2 пункт; 2) внешние ключи модифицируються в таблицах, где указаны, то - есть st_id.marks (CASCADE), d_id (RESTRICT), t_id (SETB  NULL)и єто применимо только для FK, для PK - невозможно? 3) выходит записи в таблицах уже индексированны, например, студент 1 иметт 5 оценок, 2 студент - 3, а их порядок по st_id: 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1, индексация: 1 1 1    1 1 2 2 2?

Comment: @MuscledBoy 1) доуточнил в ответе. 2) как Вы представляете действия с РК? Действие происходит, когда меняется элемент на который ссылаются. На какой элемент ссылается РК? 3) Забудьте про "порядок записей в таблице". Такого понятия не существует. Немного доуточнил 4 пункт

Comment: Благодарю Вас за содержательный и понятный ответ. Побольше бы таких